# Saving image as Doctrine2.3 blob data type

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a class which I am trying to store an image as a blob data type, using the Doctrine2.3 as the orm.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="blob")
 */
private $data;
```

It says [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html) that there is a doctrine mapping type called blob which maps a SQL BLOB to a php resource stream.When I build my data base from the class everything works fine. But when I try to insert a savedImage object into the database like this

```
$image = new SavedImage();
$data = fread(fopen($_FILES['data']['tmp_name'], 'r'), filesize($_FILES['data']['tmp_name'])); 
$image ->setData($data);
$this->entityManager->persist($image );
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

I get the following error :

```
json_encode(); Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument.
```

Im not sure what is going wrong here any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try use `file_get_contents`.

Comment: Any insights on the ORM version you are using?

Comment: @Ocramius Im using doctrine 2.3

Comment: Do you have any stack trace for that?

Answer (score 1):

add this line before setData($data);

```
$data= mb_check_encoding($data, 'UTF-8') ? $data: utf8_encode($data);
```

And for this a the [link](http://www.johnro.net/2011/06/10/php-warning-json_encode-function-json-encode-invalid-utf-8-sequence-in-argument-in-god_i_hate_this-php/) form more details